# How can I use the remote SSH extension's file selection GUI for non-remote workspaces in VS Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-remote

When I run VS code using a SSH tunnel, the open folder action triggers a small command-like explorer where I can autocomplete path. However, when running VS code locally, opening a folder triggers the usual file explorer GUI, which I find slower.

Is there a way to use the SSH way locally?

I searched the settings panel and on Google but I didn't find anything relevant.

Answer (score 0):

Remote SSH is an extension contribution from the `ms-vscode-remote.remote-ssh` extension, which is not open-source (they only expose [a GitHub repo for submitting issue tickets and feedback](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-remote-release)). But that feature being from an extension and not from the core of VS Code, I believe the answer is: No. There is not way to use that file selection UI for regular file selection outside of the purview of the Remote SSH extension. Opening files in regular VS Code workspaces uses VS Code's core behaviour, which is to use the host system's default file explorer application.